# Django settings.py

Tags: django, settings

At my project login, some settings.py environment variables are loaded to enable some behaviors:

```
unit_id = settings.COMPANY
```

When another user logged in the system changes the value of this variable, through a function, it reflects in all other users who are already active:

```
settings.COMPANY = "coke"
```

in this case, all users will see "coke" in settings.COMPANY. I believed this would be in memory and would only apply to the user section in question, because I did not write in the physical file.

I wonder if this is how Django handles the settings.py environment variables: Does it propagate dynamically to all instances opened by all users?

This variable is accessed by context_processors.py, below:

```
def units(request):
    unit_id = settings.COMPANY
```

Answer (score 1):

[You should not change settings at runtime](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/settings/#altering-settings-at-runtime).

This is (mainly) because Django doesn't know anything about it's runtime, so it's definitely possible to run multiple instances of the same Django installation. Changing a setting like this will not propagate it to any other processes.

> I wonder if this is how Django handles the settings.py environment
>   variables: Does it propagate dynamically to all instances opened by
>   all users?

Django doesn't run an instance for every user. There is one or more (if you for example use something like gunicorn or if you use multiple servers with a load balancer.) processes that listen on a certain port.

To have some changeable setting, you could specify a default value, but you should store something like the active company in the database.

Comment: So my solution, as presented above, can be used in production environment?

Comment: No, I would not recommend it. Even if it’s possible, it can lead to unwanted consequences. Store the COMPANY value in a database or a key value store like Redis

Comment: Ok, I think I can do this for COMPANY, but I have another problem: I have set settings.TIME_ZONE also at login, because each user is in a different region. Can you advise on how to set timezone after user login?